# Ordered Timeseries data / Stock Market data using structure variants

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql, time-series

I'm looking into getting some advice on organizing the time-series information into the database. My current implementation is PostgreSQL with single table for all symbols.
It is slow on getting customized information but very easy to append.
Based on the information from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/timeseries-sql-or-nosql) I wanted to replicate the structure of the database with creating a separate table per symbol. After thinking about it more careful I realized that it would be a bit hard for me to query multiple symbols based on some criteria like:

```
SELECT * FROM "all_symbols" WHERE closePrice >= 50
```

since I would need to combine those tables somehow for the search(It might be much easier than I think). I would also grow the number of tables by some unrealistic amount due to the fact that I record some statistical analysis(like stddev) per symbol per timeframe in  a separate table.

My goal is to have fast and efficient database where I can read and combine the data any possible way for the analysis and research.

Almost forgot to mention that I am looking into the Open Source implementation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to make your original schema work faster?  Do you have indexes on the columns?  With the right database design, you don't need separate tables for each symbol.

Comment: The way my main table construct is: `|date|time|symbol|the rese` where date/time/symbol is the primary key. As far as I know pk in Postgres are indexed automatically.

Comment: Is it better to implement it suing document-oriented db, like MongoDB?

Comment: I would guess that you also want an index on symbol.

Comment: Should I also create separate indexes for date / time? Also, symbol, date and time are foreign keys in the table

Comment: What about table per symbol design?

Comment: TimGL, I would suggest that you ask another question.  Post the table structure, explain the different types of queries you are running, the frequency and types of updates, and ask what the best approach would be.

Comment: @GordonLinof: I agree - this would be a better idea.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this project at GitHub, it's a free open source market data database based on top of the Microsoft SQL Server 2012:

http://github.com/kriasoft/market-data

Answer (score 0):

Put an index on `closePrice`, and use between instead of `>=`:

```
SELECT * FROM all_symbols
WHERE closePrice between 50 and <some large value>
```

one-sided ranges usually don't use an index, but between should use the index.